# Where to place firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, firebase-authentication, react-redux

I am implementing a basic firebase authentication using react and redux.
I have created protected routes as according to the react-router example found on [this link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) and everything is working fine so far.

Now, I get the loggedIn status of the user from my auth reducer which is set on user authentication, but I want to keep the loggedIn status after page refresh using onAuthStateChanged().

Where should I place the onAuthStateChanged() function? Is there any best practice to use this?

My code for reference below:

**App.js**

```
<PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
const { loggedIn } = rest;
return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
      loggedIn ? (<Component {...props} />) : (
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
      )
    )} />
  )
}

function mapStateToProps({auth}){
  return {
    loggedIn: auth.loggedIn
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

**actions_auth.js**

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }, callback ) => {
console.log(email, password)
return(dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(
      user => { 
        dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
      payload: user
    });
    callback();
  },
  error => { 
      console.log( error.message );        
      dispatch({ 
        type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
        error: error.message 
      });
    }
  )
 }
}
```

**reducer_auth.js**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  error: '',
  loading: false,
  loggedIn: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAIL_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, email: action.payload };
    case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, password: action.payload };
    case LOGIN_USER:
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: '' };
    case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:          
      return { ...state, ...INITIAL_STATE, user: action.payload, loggedIn: true };
    case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
      return { ...state, error: action.error };
    case LOGOUT_USER:
      return { ...state, ...INITIAL_STATE };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should locate it where you create redux store, should be where you render your App component.
You can look [here](https://tighten.co/blog/react-101-part-4-firebase) for more details.
If you use firebase a lot I recommend to invest some time to set-up this great library [react-redux-firebase](http://react-redux-firebase.com/)

Comment: Thanks @ykorach, I kinda solved my issue by placing the function in App.js, but I will defnitely have a look at that library.